# Can I load a Ruby class at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, class, runtime

I have a very advanced question:
if I have a complete class definition read from a ruby file(or loaded from a DB). can I instantiate that class and execute the methods.

example:
class data stored in DB string like this.

```
"class Test\n\tdef hello\n\t\tputs \"Hello World\"\n\tend\n\n\tdef check (val)\n\t\tif val == \"new\"\n\t\t\tputs \"Value was 'new' \"\n\t\telse\n\t\t\tputs \"Value was not new\"\n\tend\n\nend"
```

Comment: Does this translate to "If I load in Ruby code into Ruby can I run it?"

Comment: but I don't know what class code define in DB string

Comment: Ah, you're asking "If I have Ruby stored in a database can I import that and run it?".

Comment: @tadman Yes exactly!

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is an `eval` method as in Lisp or JavaScript. You are in luck, Ruby [has an eval method](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval).

To execute some basic code, just store it all in a string and then call

```
eval(myCodeString)
```

There are more ways to use `eval` for various circumstances. See the article I linked to for more information.

Please note that executing arbitrary strings as code is risky, as a nefarious user could inject their own Ruby code into your application a la Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) or SQL Injection.

Comment: I'd like to emphasize the risky part by adding  **PLEASE AVOID DOING THIS AT ALL COSTS**.  There's almost always another way to get the same effect, like by storing *parameters* in the database instead of code. The reason this is risky is because editing content in a database using a bug in you code is usually not nearly as hard as writing files to disk.

Comment: so how I could code it to be able to create a class along with its methods and use the methods for basic manipulation in my case?

Comment: What's the motivation behind having code in the database? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Rana store your class and applicable calls into a string and `eval` that string. But don't actually *do* that, shooting yourself with an AK-47 is safer.

Comment: @tadman I am afraid that I have to stick with it, Cant escape.!! :(

Comment: I'm supposing that because you're asking this question you don't have a functioning solution yet, so there's still time to fix this before you create a monster that will kill you or eat your company.

Comment: @tadman Actually the scenario is that how it is possible to manipulate a ruby class that is stored in a db string.and how to get the behavior of a ruby class that class like a ruby class in actual

Comment: That's the solution you're developing, not the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. (Source: [answer])  Answers need to have sufficient information so that the answer can be understood independently (as a standalone) The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and / or include a minimal example of the answer. (Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/225371)